# wpa roaming configuration does not work

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, wpa-supplicant

I am trying to configure wpa_supplicant.conf in roaming mode.I use Devuan with Sysv (=Debian without systemD).

my wpa configuration works fine:

```
pkill wpa;wpa -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf 
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 90:9a:4a:1c:23:55 (SSID='0j0' freq=2452 MHz)
wlan0: Trying to associate with 90:9a:4a:1c:23:55 (SSID='0j0' freq=2452 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with 90:9a:4a:1c:23:55
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 90:9a:4a:1c:23:55 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 90:9a:4a:1c:23:55 completed [id=0 id_str=]
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS 
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=90:9a:4a:1c:23:55 reason=4 locally_generated=1
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 90:9a:4a:1c:23:55 (SSID='0j0' freq=2452 MHz)
wlan0: Trying to associate with 90:9a:4a:1c:23:55 (SSID='0j0' freq=2452 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with 90:9a:4a:1c:23:55
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 90:9a:4a:1c:23:55 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 90:9a:4a:1c:23:55 completed [id=0 id_str=]

/etc/init.d/networking restart 
    Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not re-enable 
some interfaces ... (warning).
Reconfiguring network interfaces...Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlan0/00:45:e2:6d:e5:a3
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/00:45:e2:6d:e5:a3
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.34 from 192.168.0.33
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.34 on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK of 192.168.0.34 from 192.168.0.33
bound to 192.168.0.34 -- renewal in 3404 seconds.
```

I have got my dhcp lease, everything works fine. Now I want wpa roaming configuration. I followed instructions in /usr/share/doc/

```
vi /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf 
network={                                                                       
    ssid="0j0"                                                                  
    psk=e1e2aae2c67d91b5f745344a82ed19deb1f8ec97052530d4a9dc748ee4492703        
     id_str="test"   
} 

ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant # set location of the control socket         
#ctrl_interface_group=<group> #group admin can use wpa_cli                      
update_config=1 #allows saving changes to file that are made in cli

 vi /etc/network/interfaces 
auto lo                                                                         
iface lo inet loopback                                                          
                                                                                
allow-hotplug wlan0                                                            
#auto wlan0                                                                      
iface wlan0 inet manual                                                        
#iface wlan0 inet dhcp                                                           
wpa-driver wext                                                          
#I tried this one too:       
#wpa-driver nl80211                                                      
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf                               
                                                                                
iface test inet dhcp    

/sbin/wpa_action test reload
```

/var/log/syslog stays silent. Nothing happens. I certainly missed sthg here but dont know what?

any idea folks?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with wpa-roam and the configuration of dhcp when selecting an alternate hotspot. I had to disable the startup of wpa_supplicant from systemd and uninstall the ifupdown2 package and install the ifupdown package instead. I am running debian 11.6 and use wpa gui.

/etc/networking/interfaces

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-driver wext
    wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet dhcp
```

wpa_supplicant.conf

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="P500"
    psk="8db6253b9aa4"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
}
network={
    ssid="Nokia 3.1"
    psk="6a8f704f219c"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
}
```